# Samsung CLP-31x printer not working

Tags: printing, cups

So, my Samsung CLP-31x series printer stopped printing from Debian 6 applications.  Closed source applications such as Chrome work, as does Foxit under Wine.  Currently using the foo2qpdl CUPS driver.  Tried Splix 2.0 from the website, nothing works, not even Foxit.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this repository:

```
deb http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ debian extra
```

I use CLX-3185FN and the drivers from this repo work great.

Take a look at the author's website:

http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/

Comment: Looks promising.  This will require some surgery on my system, but hopefully doable soon.